# Order of evaluation for ternary operator in C

Tags: c, standards, conditional-operator

I am aware that according to the standard, `fun(++a, a)` should be avoided since second argument is not well defined.

However, is this formulation safe:

```
(++a ? a : 10);
```

I tested this snippet and it works as expected, *ie* for `a = -1` it evaluates as `10`, and for any other `a` it evaluates as `a+1`. Is this well defined in the standard, or it strongly depends on the compiler?

Comment: Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: According to this, it is safe to assume that second and third arguments are evaluated *after the first argument*. Nevertheless, I would still like to get confirmation by someone more experienced.

Comment: It's  not safe from a code review - I would still fire you:)

Comment: @MartinJames You could not afford me in the first place ;)

Comment: @Marko lol, see you later down at the JobCentre:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is well defined.

In a ternary expression, the first part is evaluated first.  Then based on that value, *either* the second or the third part is evaluated.  So `++a` is guaranteed to be evaluated before `a` is possible evaluated.

This is explained in section 6.5.15p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  first  operand  is  evaluated;  **there  is  a  sequence  point  between  its  evaluation  and  the evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated)**.  The second operand is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if the  first  compares  equal  to  0;  the  result  is  the  value  of  the  second  or  third  operand(whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.